# Raw output from controller action method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to output some text *without* using a template. Right now I have a controller action method that's altering the Content-Type of the response and I want to display the text directly, without creating a template file (a single-line template file is useless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`render :text`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text) in Rails 2.3:

> You can send plain text – with no markup at all – back to the browser by using the `:text` option to `render` [...]

So this:

```
render :text => 'whatever'
```

should do what you want.

The same thing works in [Rails 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.2/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text).

Comment: @omouse: See "Rendering Text": http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render